# print elements in list in reversed order and on a new line

Tags: list, newline

I want to print all elements in this list in reversed order and every element in this list must be on a new line.
For example if the list is ['i', 'am', 'programming', 'with', 'python'] it should print out:
python
with
programming
am
i
What is the best way to do this?

```
def list():
    words = []
    while True:
        output = input("Type a word: ")
        if output == "stop":
            break
        else:
            words.append(output)
    for elements in words:
        print(elements)
list()
```

Answer (score 0):

generic :

```
for(i=wordsArry.size();i--;i<0){
    pritnln(wordsArry[i]+"/n")
}
```

- Start iteration from the end of the list - last element in it.
- Then iterate backwards - decrease iterator by 1 till you reach 0.
- Print each element plus new line symbol - might depend on OS,
  language.

Answer (score 0):

In Python you can reverse a list in place by:

```python
words = ['i', 'am', 'programming', 'with', 'python']
words.reverse()
for w in words:
    print(w)
```

If you want to iterate in reverse but keep the original order, you can use a slice:

```python
for w in words[::-1]:
    print(w)
```

Slice syntax is [begin:end:step], where `begin` (incl) and `end` (excl) indices are omitted (get all elements) and the step -1 returns a slice with the elements in reverse order.

Both methods produce the same output.